# How to pass arguments when calling `source` command

Tags: c++, arguments, tcl

I need to run `source` command from c++ program and pass filename and also some arguments. Is it possible? I want to use them in script like command line arguments (with `argc, argv0, ...`). http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/source.n.html here is not specified how to do it.

Comment: In a comment to one of the answers you mentioned that you're calling `source` from a C++ program. That is important information that you should include in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley its updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing this from C or C++, you should:

1. Initialise the Tcl library and create a Tcl interpreter.
2. Set the global variables `argv0`, `argv` and `argc` to the values expected by a normal Tcl script. This is exactly what *tclsh* does; the variables are entirely ordinary apart from being initialised this way.

   - `argv0` is the name of the “main” script, which might be the script you're about to `source`.
   - `argv` is a Tcl list of all the other arguments; `argc` is the length of that list.
3. Use `Tcl_FSEvalFileEx(interp,pathPtr,encoding)` to execute the file; the `source` command is a very thin wrapper around that call. You probably want to pass the *encoding* argument as `NULL`, and the *pathPtr* argument is a `Tcl_Obj` reference.

Answer (score 2):

If your script accepts the arguments in `argv`, just set this variable before you source this script.

But if this script calls exit, it will terminate the entire process, usually not what you want. You could use a slave interp to avoid this.

Comment: The problem is I am calling source command from C++ program by creating custom interpreter and calling its eval, so no predefined arguments are accessible, I want to pass them when calling eval

Comment: If you come from the C side, use Tcl_SetVar to set `argv`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 predefined variables:

```
$argc - number items of arguments passed to a script.
$argv - list of the arguments.
$argv0 - name of the script.
```

So in your case, assuming the file sourced is in the same directory and its name is passed as a first argument:

```
source [lindex $argv 0]
```

Comment: I know how to get arguments passed by command line. I don't know how to pass them to `source` command because it accepts only filename

Comment: `source` invokes the Tcl interpreter within the same process, so the 3 predefined variables are accessible by the sourced script as well. Can you not run the script that you are sourcing as a subprocess? If you use `exec` you can pass new arguments.

Comment: The problem is I am calling source command from C++ program by creating custom interpreter and calling its eval, so no predefined arguments are accessible, I want to pass them when calling eval